# Dynamically create SQL statements through .NET Program

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, oracle, ado.net

I'm working on a small application that verifies some entries in an Oracle database by comparing some entries on an excel sheet to the tables in an Oracle database so I'm only working on querying the database and nothing too complex.

I'm trying to get this to be completely dynamic so as I wouldn't have to make any code changes regardless of what the queries are however I'm running into a small issue when the table I'm querying has numeric and string type values.

```
If chkConnState() Then
sSql = "SELECT * FROM " & workSheetName & " WHERE "
For i = 1 To ds.Tables.Item(0).Columns.Count - 1
sSql &= ds.Tables.Item(0).Columns.Item(i).ToString & " = " & ds.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(i).ToString & " AND "
Next
newSql = sSql.Substring(0, sSql.Length - 4)
End If
```

Here I am only gathering the SQL statement to query the table against.  I grab the columns and rows information from the Excel(the information I know is correct and am using to check against what's in the table) and then remove the ending 'AND' from the query.

Is there any easy way to determine if the column is numeric or string? The issue I'm having now is I have no idea how to determine where I should add the "'" & value & "'" in string values dynamically. I would say just query by the PK but I'm not sure there's an easy way to find this either as it's different for every table and doing it the way above I will only retrieve one record rather than possible multiple.    Is there a better way to go about this to make it dynamic?

Comment: Try using `Integer.TryParse` or `Decimal.TryParse` on the ToString items.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow. Are you trying to say how do I know the use when to use where colname = '1' vs where colname = 1. I know that you can quote the numeric data on some databases without problem -- don't recall if Oracle allows this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As LarsTech said you can use TryParse to determine if the values are numeric.

```
If(Double.TryParse(ds.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(i).ToString, Nothing), _
ds.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(i).ToString, _ 
"'" & ds.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(i).ToString & "'")
```

This will put single quotations around any value that is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Func to check fields easily

```
public static Func<string, bool> isNumeric = x => { int i = 0; return Int32.TryParse(x, out i); };
```

Simple usage

if (isNumeric(yourField))
{

} else
{

}